# How can I find saved WiFi passwords within non-rooted phone?

Tags: wifi-password

I have Android phone which is non-rooted. How can I know the saved WiFi passwords in my phone?

Comment: I'm afraid you can't, since the password is saved on the system which you need root to access it.

Answer (score 1):

Without root there is no way to find the passwords of Wi-Fi networks on your device. That's because the Wi-Fi passwords are saved in the root folders.

On CyanogenMod devices, and possibly other AOSP ROMs, you should be able to grab it from the `/data/misc/wifi/wpa_supplicant.conf` file. Without root this is not possible since you won't have permission to read the `/data` directories.