# How can I retrieve WiFi passwords via (rooted) ADB on a Pixel 4a with LineageOS?

Tags: root-access, lineageos, android-13, wifi-password

I have a Pixel 4a with LineageOS (Android 13) that can connect to various WiFi networks. Not all passwords can be viewed through the WiFi page in settings, e.g. those with WPA Enterprise or those added through third-party app.

How can I retrieve the passwords of these WiFi networks?

I tried finding the location of it via Google, but all the suggested paths turned out to be empty or missing:

- `/data/misc/wifi/WifiConfigStore.xml` (does not exist)
- `/data/misc/wifi/wpa_supplicant.conf` (does not exist)

`/data/misc/wifi/wpa_supplicant` is a directory, but it is empty. The only other thing in `/data/misc/wifi` is the empty `/data/misc/wifi/socket` folder.

This question is **not a duplicate** of the following questions:

- [How can I find a saved Wi-Fi password?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/21296/52118) – <s>`/data/misc/wifi/WifiConfigStore.xml`</s>, <s>`/data/wifi/`</s>, <s>`/data/etc/wifi/`</s>, <s>`/data/misc/wifi/`</s>
- [How can I find saved WiFi passwords within non-rooted phone?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/106191/52118) – <s>`/data/misc/wifi/wpa_supplicant.conf`</s>
- [How to find saved wifi password?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/25585/52118) – Show password doesn't work for some networks, explained above.
- [How to find the Wi-Fi Password of a Connected Network on Android mobile](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/162837/52118) – <s>`/data/misc/wifi/wpa-supplicant.conf`</s>, <s>`/data/wifi`</s>, <s>`/data/misc/wifi`</s>
- [Where can I find saved WiFi AP passwords?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/114323/52118) – <s>`data/misc/wifi/wpa_supplicant.conf`</s>
- [Retrieve WiFi password](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/132391/52118) – `adb backup com.android.providers.settings` produces an empty archive
- [How do i recover my wifi pass from android using adb?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/113946/52118) – <s>`/data/misc/wifi/wpa_supplicant.conf`</s>
- [How to show wifi password?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/66039/52118) – <s>`/data/misc/wifi/wpa_supplicant.conf`</s>

Comment: Monitoring file wrote activity could show you where the WiFi passwords are stired. I would use Termux to install inotify-tools for arm64 and then use it in Termux or vis adb with root permissions to monitor the data tree of your file-system for write operations when you add a new WiFi password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot give you the direct answer but cannot comment yet on Stack Exchange.
However, with ADB you can try searching for it in two ways.

1. search for file names

`cd / ; find | grep supp | grep conf`

2. or take a known SSID password and search for it in the files.

`cd / ; grep -R "known SSID password"`

Number 1) is supposed to give you various names, like wpa_***supp***licant.***conf*** or bcm_***supp***.*conf* or whatever the file might be named. It seems to not always carry the same name.

Number 2) would give you the file name IF your Wi-Fi password appears in clear text in a file. Other passwords should likewise be in that file or at least in that directory.

Alternatively, if ADB is just an alternative for you to find the passwords, this app had worked for me on a Samsung Note 10+ with original firmware in which the "regular" location also hadn't worked; that is my reason for answering here.

https://android.izzysoft.de/repo/apk/ua.sytor.wifipass
-Sources are linked from the site on GitHub.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me find the config. It was in `/data/misc/apexdata/com.android.wifi/WifiConfigStore.xml`. https://github.com/syt0r/WifiPass/blob/1c649924649cb182e60535f27384793d2b6c09fc/app/src/main/java/ua/sytor/wifipass/core/network_data_collector/NetworkDataCollectorContract.kt#L38-L42

Answer (score 1):

On this Phone/OS combination, it turned to be in `/data/misc/apexdata/com.android.wifi/WifiConfigStore.xml`.

Check out [boro's answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/256524/52118) for a more general approach on how to find it. I simply found it in the source code of the suggested app: https://github.com/syt0r/WifiPass/blob/1c649924649cb182e60535f27384793d2b6c09fc/app/src/main/java/ua/sytor/wifipass/core/network_data_collector/NetworkDataCollectorContract.kt#L38-L42.